# ClangAST：How to get superclass method Implementation

Tags: objective-c, clang, dump

```
//person.h
@interface person : NSObject
//method declaration 
- (void) hello;
- (void) world;
- (void) personName;
@end
//person.m
@implementation person
//method implementation 
- (void) hello{
    NSLog(@"hello!!!");
}
- (void) world{
    NSLog(@"world!!!");
}
@end
//student.h
@interface student : person
- (void) printName;
- (void) printAge;
- (void) printStuNo;
@end
//student.m
@implementation student
- (void) printName{
    NSLog(@"my name is student!!!");
}
- (void) printAge{
    NSLog(@"My age is 18!!!");
}
@end
```

I use `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only /Users/Desktop/testCpp/testCpp/student.m`

I need to get `person`'s implementation method, such as `hello` and `world` by `student`'s dump tree.
`person` and `student` are inheritance relationship.`student`'s dump tree only has `student`'s method implementation. When I use `superInterface->getImplementation();`, it return `null`. So, I can not use `ObjCImplementationDecl * imp = superInterface->getImplementation(); imp->methods;` to find `person`'s  implementation method.

How can I do that?

Comment: person and student are in different files. person is in [person.h & person.m] file;
student is in [student.h & student.m] file.